# Docker compose memory limit and JVM heap space

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, heap-memory

Yesterday I had a problem with a containerized (Docker) Java Spring Boot application.
When I'd tried to upload a 5000x5000 pixel image (about 5MB) I had an OOE (out of memory) error during the thumbnail generation.

So I increased the memory limit in this way

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 1024M
```

but has not been enough to solve. So after a little bit of searches I added this environment variable into the docker-compose.yml

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: '-Xmx1024m'
```

and now it works.

My question is: JVM doesn't take all the memory allocated for the container specified in resource > memory > limit: 1024M?

Why is necessary to pass the `-Xmx` parameter in order to increase the heap space?

Comment: For Docker/Kubernetes usages, it is probably better to rely on `-XX:MaxRamPercentage=80` or something like that. And for reference, recent Java versions actually look to the cgroup limits, but by default it's pretty low (something like 25% for cgroup memory limit > 1GB).